# SSH Ubuntu from different network

Tags: virtualbox, ssh, openssh

I have Ubuntu 16.04 LTS on my VirtualBox.

How can I SSH through a device from another network?

Host : Windows 10
VM: Ubuntu 16.04

I want to SSH with putty from another network.

Also how can I SSH from an Android device?

I've set port forwarding

```
192.168.56.1   2222    10.0.2.15     2222
```

Comment: What network type do you have configured for the Ubuntu virtual machine?

Comment: NAT for now because I can use putty on host to ssh

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using NAT, you must first configure port forwarding (chapter 6.3.1 off VirtualBox manual).

You should configure a port on your Windows machine (for example 2222) to correspond to the VM's port 22.

Then you can connect with PuTTY to the IP address of your Windows host and port 2222.

Same applies to Android. You need to find an SSH application on Play Store (or whatever you use) and use the same connection details.

Comment: I've set the port forwarding and it only can ssh from host not Android and from other network

Comment: You need to edit and include all the details in your quotation. Writing "I configured everything, but it does not work" will not get you any solution.

Comment: You should set port forwarding from 2222 to 22 (not to 2222).

Answer (score 0):

If you SSH from guest to any other device, virtualbox will take care of NAT'ing and it should work out of the box.

If you plan to SSH from PC to your guest, while in NAT, you must indeed open port forwarding in VB > Machine > Settings > Network > Port Forwarding

If you have no particular reason for NATing your device, I suggest you use use bridged networking so your guest behaves just as a regular device, on your network.